# brew cask install safari-technology-preview not working on a computer, but works on another

Tags: terminal, safari, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I just tried to install Safari Technology Preview via "brew cask install" on two different MacBooks. On the first one it gets installed with no problems. On the other one I get "Error: Cask 'safari-technology-preview' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists."

Both Brew are up-to-date.

What could it be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

To install Safari Technology Preview you need to tap a separate Homebrew repository:

```sh
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask safari-technology-preview
```

Answer (score -1):

A minor update to the syntax and repository address of the below answer.

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions
brew install --cask safari-technology-preview
```

Comment: You should suggest an edit rather than add a new answer